# Flutter column widget: childs with different heights

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a small test app with a large central area onto which i will render an image and a smaller bottom area that will contains an horizontal scrollable list of widgets. Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';    
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';    
import 'package:photo_app_ui_test/fxmanager/fx_manager.dart';

////    
void main() {
  runApp(SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SampleAppPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SampleAppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SampleAppPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleAppPageState createState() => _SampleAppPageState();
}

class _SampleAppPageState extends State<SampleAppPage> {
  FxManager fxManager;
  bool      showLoadingDialog = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //loadData();
    fxManager = FxManager();
    fxManager.init().then( (dynamic) => initInterface() );
  }


  void initInterface(){
    setState(() {
      showLoadingDialog = false;
    });
  }

  getBody() {
    if (showLoadingDialog) {
      return getProgressDialog();
    } else {
      return getEffectsWidget();//getListView();
    }
  }

  getProgressDialog() {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }

  getEffectsWidget() {
    return

      Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Expanded(child: Container(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
                child: Center(child: Text("Image")))),
            Flexible( child: Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 0),
                child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: _getListData()
                )))
          ]);
  }

  _getListData() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      widgets.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              /*
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),*/
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                    children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.add), Text("Add")],
                  )),
            ],
          )));
    }
    return widgets;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Sample App"),
        ),
        body: getBody());
  }


}
```

produce this result:

[image]

I would like to make the green box's height as small as possible:

[image]

If the `ListView` widget is a direct children of the `Column` widget, the usual `Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height` exception is thrown. So i have to embed it inside a `Flexible` or `Expanded`.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: "I would like to make the green box's height as small as possible". I could rephrase it like:"How to make the green box's height as small as possible, like displayed in the second image?".

Comment: Haven't you already achieved this in the 2nd picture ?

Comment: Ahah, nope. I edited it with Gimp ^^

Comment: You can just have the desired output by computing the ratio in height, for example if you made the flex factor 4 for the image it should give you what you want, otherwise you will have to give the image a fixed height but I know that is not something you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desired Output:

```
getEffectsWidget() {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              child: Center(child: Text("Image")))),

       Container(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: _getListData(),
              ),
            ),
      )
    ]);
  }

static _getListData() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      widgets.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0), 
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              /*
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),*/
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                    children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.add), Text("Add")],
                  )),
            ],
          )));
    }
    return widgets;
  }
```

Comment: This solution, while achieves something similar to what i want, does not make the green box height as smal as possible. Depending on the flex value of the first Expanded widget, you could even get an exception lilke "A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.1 pixels on the bottom" on a device, while no exception on another device.

Comment: removed flex factor - its auto adjust now.